# How to build GO executable with maven

Tags: maven, go

I have my Go source code, after `go build`, an executable is generated, which accepts some parameters to produce the output.
Is there any way build the executable from maven build with any plugins?

Comment: Wow, that's a new level... What for?

Comment: @NestorSokil To integrate open-source GO code in my JAVA application

Comment: Are you going to call Go-code through JNI? Please add these details into your question.

Comment: What have you tried? What problems did you encounter?

Comment: @Flimzy, I used MVN GoLang Wrapper plugin during the maven build, Build got succeeded and jar file has been generated. But I'm not sure, its the right way?

Comment: @NestorSokil, not through JNI. I just need an executable from my go source code when ever I perform maven build.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just put your `go build` command into a shell script and run it with this plugin:

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>Build Go binary</id>
      <phase>generate-sources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>exec</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <executable>${basedir}/build-golang-app.sh</executable>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Other option is this [Golang plugin](https://github.com/raydac/mvn-golang) which is more feature-rich and specific to this problem. However for simple use cases I would still go with Shell script.

Comment: That was really helpful. In both the cases do we need to have GO installed in local?

Comment: @Akshaychittal For shell script - definitely (yet you can script it to pull GO SDK/docker image). But from the docs of the plugin, you can specify the golang version to build with and it will install it from official SDK site distribution.

Answer (score 4):

there is [special plugin for maven to build golang projects](https://github.com/raydac/mvn-golang), it is called mvn-golang-wrapper, [there is some example Hello World project to show how to make simple project](https://github.com/raydac/mvn-golang-example), [a lot of examples can be found in the maven plugin project repository](https://github.com/raydac/mvn-golang/tree/master/mvn-golang-examples) . The plugin allows work with maven central and it allows to share golang projects and their parts through maven repository, also it has special system to work with repositories and use versions through branch, tag and revision.